# What does getElementsByName("secilenil")[0] mean?

Tags: javascript

```
var sec = document.getElementsByName("secilenil")[0];
```

I did not understand the end of this statement which is [0].What does this mean? *"secilenil"* is the name of select element.

Comment: Notice the `s` in `getElementsByName`. It returns an array of elements which have the same name. Hence you pick the first one using `[0]`

Comment: @abhitalks - It's not really an array, even though for the most part it behaves as one.

Comment: @Lix: Yup. it is an htmlcollection. i just said array as it behaved like one here.

Comment: @Lix: on second thoughts, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection . It says: "*HTMLCollection is an interface representing a generic collection (array) of elements*"

Comment: did you actually search? google.com

Answer (score 6):

`getElementsByName` returns a `NodeList` of all elements with a `name` attribute equal to `secilenil`. Using `[0]` selects the first found node.

The `[0]` notation is similar to that of an array - it means you want to extract the element at the specific index.

[MDN reference.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName)